# Change the default StorageClass with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

According to the documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/ if wi want to change the default Storage Class we should patch it.

Template to create new Storage Class

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: encrypted
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: ext4
  encrypted: true
```

I have tried to add to the template:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: gp2
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "false"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
```

And got an error: `gp2 already exist`

How to patch/update default Storage Class (make it non-default) with Helm template?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with helm?

Answer (score 2):

Helm can only manage resources created by itself, and you are trying to alter an already existing resource. You can either:

- delete the gp2 storage class before applying the chart and helm will recreate it
- delete the gp2 template from your chart, and patch the gp2 storage class manually before applying the chart